# Error SQL: ORA-00904: invalid identifier en una Tabla

Tags: oracle-11g

Al crear la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE login (
id       number(10) NOT NULL,
user     varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
password varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
email    varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
pasadmin varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
rol      number(10) NOT NULL);
```

me marca que el atributo user es invalido 
se corrige cambiando el nombre de user 
pero quisiera saber porque USER es invalido!!!
Espero puedan ayudarme...

Comment: Prueba a usar las comillas (el acento) para enmarcar los nombres de tablas, suele ocurrir que un nombre como user o from sean nombres reservados. También puedes usar otros nombres aceptados como users, person, usuario o usuarios. Pero si sigues interesado en user, prueba así ´user´ (el otro acento en realidad, no puedo ponerlo porque es usado en los comentarios para marcar palabras)

Answer (score -1):

Creo que es una palabra reservada. Tomado de https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58234/vol2_wor.htm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]